# HandlerInterceptor has an Object hander parameter, what types will get passed into the interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The `HandlerInterceptor` interface has a parameter `Object handler`, which means implementing code has to do type checking on the handler object in order to use it, and cast it as appropriate.

Code snippets I've found seem to assume the handler is always a `HandlerMethod` object and return true if this isn't the case, but I want to understand why this seems to be a common implementation to make a robust implementation.

A standard way of implementing this interface seems to be:

```java
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            // ...
            return x; // whether or not to proceed with execution
        }
        return true; // fallback value in case handler wasn't a HandlerMethod
    }
}
```

The Spring javadoc seems to ignore the fact that the interface has an Object type in it, it's very unhelpful for my understanding of this interface.

Some questions that might aid my understanding of how this interface is supposed to be implemented:

- Why is `true` a sensible default if we get a handler that's not the object we expect it to be?
- Which types can an `HandlerInterceptor` take for its `handler` parameter?
- Under what circumstances could `handler` be a different type, if any?
- Why is it an `Object`, not a `HandlerMethod`, parameter?

Comment: a handler can be anything. For an annotation driven implementation it will be a `HandlerMethod` when using a `SimpleControllerHandlerMapping` it will be the class. Basically for each `HandlerAdapter` that can handle a request it could be the type that is handled by that `HandlerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the `handler` argument can be any type for which a [`HandlerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerAdapter.html) exists. Most commonly used will be the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` utilizing a `HandlerMethod`.

But it could be a regular class, a servlet, or even a function (when using the functional approach). Spring Web Services also has an implementation as well as Spring Integration.

Spring itself will support the following out-of-the-box

- [`HandlerMethod`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html)
- [`HandlerFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/function/support/HandlerFunctionAdapter.html)
- [`Controller`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.html)
- [`Servlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleServletHandlerAdapter.html)
- [`HttpRequestHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.html)
- [`WsdlDefinition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter.html) (Spring Web Services)
- [`XsdDefinition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/XsdSchemaHandlerAdapter.html) (Spring Web Services)

So no it isn't always a `HandlerMethod` but it will be for most users.

Comment: Thanks, these are the missing pieces I couldn't find. 
Since I will be exclusively using the default handler adapter and request-mapped methods, I believe in my case `handler` will always be a `HandlerMethod` then.

Comment: Well not entirely. If you serve static resources you also have a `HttpRequestHandler` possibility.

Comment: That's good to know, and informs my choice of default value to return when the handler is not a `HandlerMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what javadoc of `HandlerInterceptor#preHandle()` says:

> Interception point before the execution of a handler. Called after HandlerMapping determined an appropriate handler object, but before **HandlerAdapter invokes the handler**.
> **DispatcherServlet processes a handler** in an execution chain, consisting of any number of interceptors, with the handler itself at the end. With this method, **each interceptor can decide to abort the execution chain**, typically sending an HTTP error or writing a custom response.

This means interceptors are not supposed to touch the `handler` at all so they don't need to know anything about it. Their only job is to decide whether to pass the request further or not.

BTW, none of the standard `HandlerInterceptor#preHandle()` implementations in  `org.springframework.web.servlet.*` try to analyze the true `handler` parameter type and do any logic based on it.

> Why is it an Object, not a HandlerMethod, parameter?

From the `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping#getHandler()` javadoc:

> Return a handler and any interceptors for this request. The choice may be made on request URL, session state, or any factor the implementing class chooses.
> The returned HandlerExecutionChain contains a handler Object, rather than even a tag interface, so that handlers are not constrained in any way. For example, a HandlerAdapter could be written to allow another framework's handler objects to be used.

Comment: I'm aware of what the javadoc says, but it's very unhelpful for the reasons I pointed out in my post. I'm trying to read the annotation on the handling method, so I can implement an interceptor with common logic and have handler-specific parameters.
`HandlerMethod` has a method for obtaining the annotation: `getMethodAnnotation`. It seems odd to me that the interceptor interface provides the handler, but you're not supposed to look at it?
The `HandlerMethod` class seems to exist specifically to obtain information about the handler it's about to invoke. So why isn't it passed as such?

Comment: To respond to your second comment: The spring-boot `LongTaskTimingHandlerInterceptor` seems to do exactly this cast to `HandlerMethod` as well in order to obtain its annotations, and uses some default value otherwise. So it does seem to expect this type as well. I'm just confused about the fact that the handler is not of type `HandlerMethod` in the interface.

Comment: Updated the answer. What kind of common logic do you want to implement in your interceptor?

Comment: The edit you made (explaining *why* it is an Object) is useful, thanks! It seems like for Spring(-Boot) handlers we can indeed assume they are `HandlerMethod` objects then. The common logic my interceptors would handle are things like ratelimiting of requests (with the annotation configuring the allowed execution frequency per handler). This is not possible in the Filter stage, since the handler is not resolved yet, so must be done through an interceptor, as far as I'm aware. It can also be killswitches (disabling of *specific* handlers, which also needs access to the handler object).

Comment: Thanks for clarification - that looks legit. You're correct, a filter intercepts requests before they reach the `DispatcherServlet` where the notion of a handler appears.